# How to write this code into a one lined command

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, shell

I have a curl command which return some json result.

```
{  
    "all":[  
    {
        "id":"1",
        "actions":[  
            "power",
            "reboot"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "actions":[  
            "shutdown"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "actions":[  
            "backup"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I retreive the data actions with this command :

```
curl -s https://DOMAIN/API -H "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN" | python -c "import sys, json, re; print [ i['allowed_actions'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['servers']]"
```

But I would like to use this code in python on the command line :

```
for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['all']:
    if i['id'] == '1':
        print(i['actions'])
```

I tried this :

```
curl -s https://DOMAIN/API -H "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN" | python -c "import sys, json, re; print [ if i['id'] == '1': i['actions'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['servers']]"
```

But it returns a syntax error

```
File "<string>", line 1
    import sys, json, re; for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['all']:\nif i['id'] == '1':\nprint(i['actions'])
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you want to print this expression:

```
[i['actions'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['all'] if i['id'] == '1']
```

This filters the sub dictionary/ies where `id == 1` and builds a list with the `actions` data.

so adapted to curl command line:

```
curl -s https://DOMAIN/API -H "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN" | python -c "import sys, json, re; print([i['actions'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['all'] if i['id'] == '1'])"
```

Feeding to a simple python command line works:

```
[['power', 'reboot']]
```

id seems unique, so maybe it's better to avoid returning a 1-element list:

```
next((i['actions'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['all'] if i['id'] == '1'),None)
```

with that expression it yields `['power', 'reboot']` or `None` if not found

Answer (score 3):

Give [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) a try. It's a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON parser, and it's a standard package in Ubuntu (`apt install jq`) and Red Hat (`yum install jq`).

```
$ curl ... | jq -c '.all[] | select(.id=="1").actions' 
["power","reboot"]
```

It plays nice with both JSON and standard UNIX tools. If you want to feed the output to regular tools use `-r`:

```
$ curl ... | jq -r '.all[] | select(.id=="1").actions[]' 
power
reboot
```

Comment: I want to avoid using third parties